# LocalReport not showingimage from Database source

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I am giving support to a Winforms App. I didn't develop it.
They updated it to use the latest version of Microsoft.ReportViewer.
Recently a bug was reported, some images that used to show are not showing any more.

I am at a complete lost here, I checked the rdlc and as far as I can see it is binding the Image to the correct field.

The DataSources of the LocalReport are being added and they contain the Image.

```
public byte[] Image { get; set; }
```

I debugged an the Image field has bytes.

I have been searching trhough internet but I can't seem to find the cause of the issue.

We are using:

- Visual Studio 2012
- Microsoft Report Viewer 11
- Target Framework => .Net 4.0
- Framework Instaled => .Net 4.5

Any advice you could give me would be greatly appreciated, I am sorry if this is a rather simple question!
Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Is your object that you are setting as the data source have complex types, or just primitive types. Report Viewer has known issues & workarounds when trying to bind to a complex type.

Comment: Thanks @CamBruce, There are 3 DataSources, from what I checked all of them have normal types, not really primitive though: string, bool, List<double>, byte[], enum. But they are nothing out of the ordinary though :(

Comment: @Dzyann You should make sure the `DataSource` containing Image data, try showing the image someway. Second, you should create a separate demo (with the same version of Microsoft Report Viewer) and see it in action. With all the information you provided, I don't think it can be debugged remotely.